# How to move an entire directory if a file with certain extension is found in that directory using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I'm new to python as well as stack overflow so if  I'm asking a silly question my apologies.

Here's what I'm trying to do, I have many games in my PC which are placed in random folders ex: one game is in **G:\test1\folder1\gamename** other game is in **G:\test1\folder2\gamename** etc. What I'm trying to do is scan the entire **G:\test1** directory using **os.walk** and if a .exe file exists in any folder I want the entire tree where that .exe file exists (with the name of that folder) to be moved to **G:\test1\Games** directory. I used shutil.copytree () to do this it is working fine but I'm not getting gamename folder in the destination

Ex : if  source directory is **G:\test1\limbo**
and the destination directory is **G:\test1\games**
I'm getting all the contents copied to the folder **G:\test1\games\[here**]. but I want the contents to goto 
**G:\test1\games\limbo\[here]**

```
import os, shutil
src = "G:\\test1"
dst = src+"\\games"
os.chdir(src)

for i, j, k in os.walk(src):
    for h in k:
        if h.endswith(".exe"):
            shutil.copytree(i, dst)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a bit of the source code where you are performing your write operation?

Comment: I've updated it please check

Comment: @ChandreshGS Your code raises `NameError`.

Comment: Try putting another \ at the end of `games` in your `dst`

Comment: You still have a lot of errors in your example. A space before import, a capital I instead of something more sensible not to be mixed, an letter l instead of capital I, and chdir() is completely unnecessary in this example, and it is not imported anyway. It would have to be os.chdir(src).  Also, you are missing a break in if block. If you do not exit the loop the same directory will be copied with each .exe encountered. So, what if a game has 5 exe's?

Comment: Okay bro ignore those things I just want the logic

Comment: Just logic is in my answer. Should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the folder's name and create it in G:\test1 before copying. Or use shutil.move() on it if you want to move the dir as you said.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
    if any((fn.lower().endswith(".exe") for fn in filenames)):
        shutil.move(dirpath, dst)
        # Or:
        # os.makedirs(os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(dirpath)))
        # shutil.copytree(dirpath, os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(dirpath)))
```

Comment: Thanks bro will try and let you know

Comment: Getting file exists error (winerror 183) cannot create a file when that file already exists

Comment: Of course you cannot. What did you expect? Empty your G:\test1 first. As for duplicates, you may handle them or just ignore them by using try-except block or checking in advance using os.path.exists().